# Select vertices/edges while using the move gizmo

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I am moving to blender from 3ds max, is it possible to select vertices/edges while using the move gizmo without having to deselect the vertices and select again using the box (B shortcut)?

I want to be able to drag a box without deselecting the current selection and not having to to deselect by clicking somewhere, press b to select a new vertex and move.

This is very frustrating and slow.

Comment: Use the selection tool and then G to move. Shift to add to the selection and Ctrl to remove from the selection.

Comment: You will always move all selected verts. If you are moving one at a time, a single click will select a new vert and deselect the old one. You can enable [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html#edit-mode) if you want to select one vert and also move others surrounding it.